# ENV[ ] is not working in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my rails application have added a file **secrets.env** and in that file I have added the following code

```
API_KEY=Your_VAlid_Key
```

In user_controller I added below code

```
api_key = ENV["API_KEY"]
```

but api_key variable is not getting any value. Is there anything more I need to do

Thanks in advance

Comment: secrets.env? Didn't you mean secrets.yml?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use file name as **.env**  not give any name to the file.